# Ubuntu 20.04 icons are not shown after upgrade

Tags: 20.04, icons

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 all default icons in system are not shown. Only placeholder for image is displayed.

How can i fix this? Maybe reloading all of default icons in the system?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just reinstall ubuntu desktop and themes using $ apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session ubuntu-desktop. It may be due to improper installation.

Comment: Reinstalling ubuntu desktop with apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session ubuntu-desktop did not helped.

Comment: Try to reinstall gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-extra and gnome-themes-extra-data as well use gnome-tweaks too